# find the column names of the missing values in a pyspark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a dataframe -

```
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+
| id|    name|  city|state|country|
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+
|  1|abhishek|  pune| null|   null|
|  2| devansh|  pune|   mh|  india|
|  3| urvashi|bglore|   ka|   null|
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+
```

i want to have a new column 'audit' that would have a list of columns that has null values for each row,
so the 1st row in audit column would have [state,country], 2nd empty and 3rd [country]

i think we can use isNull function here but i am not sure how to get the list of column names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work, using `isNull`:

```
df.withColumn("audit", F.array(*[F.when(F.col(col).isNull(), F.lit(col)) for col in df.schema.names]))\
.withColumn("audit", F.expr("filter(audit, x -> x is not null)"))\
.show()
```

Input:

```
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+
| id|    name|  city|state|country|
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+
|  1|abhishek|  pune| null|   null|
|  2| devansh|  pune|   mh|  india|
|  3| urvashi|bglore|   ka|   null|
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+----------------+
| id|    name|  city|state|country|           audit|
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+----------------+
|  1|abhishek|  pune| null|   null|[state, country]|
|  2| devansh|  pune|   mh|  india|              []|
|  3| urvashi|bglore|   ka|   null|       [country]|
+---+--------+------+-----+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, It did work. However, I am fairly new to this tech so I have some doubts. df.withColumn("audit",F.array([when(F.col(col).isNull(),F.lit(col)) for col in df.schema.names]))\
        .withColumn("audit",F.expr("filter(audit, x->x is not null)")).show() this is also working, so why we used * and f.when ? and 2nd, can we write filter condition without using expr, something like df.filter ?

Comment: @Nitish * is used to expand a list to parameters. Its works without * as there is an overloaded method that accepts list itself. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html

Comment: This filter is to filter elements within the array, df.filter is to filter rows from dataframe, there is an F.filter as well but it was introduced in 3.1.0 - but I didn't knew which version you're using. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html